# DOM element inside backbone template doesn't respond to event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have 2 Backbone views. One view (AppView) represents the entire collection and when it fetches it, parses the collection and generates the individual model views for each model in the collection.

The one issue I'm having is when the model views are created, they no longer respond to my `click` event which is a method of the model view. In the model view, if I replace `tagName` with `el`, the event can fire, however it fires for every single model in the collection instead of the individual model.

I think it has something to do with the events being untied from the template on load but I can't figure out how to tie back in, or generate the template without untying them.

```
// INDIVIDUAL ITEMS WITHIN THE VIEW
ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
// el: '#item-block', // click event shows an action for all 20 models within the collection
tagName: '.item-wrapper', // click event not heard
template: _.template($('#template').html()),
events: {
    'click.details': 'fireModel', // .details is a div inside of the template
},
initialize: function () {

    // _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'fireModel');
    this.render();

},
render: function() {

    var holder   = $('#item-block');

    if(this.model.attributes.caption == null) {
        var cloned = _.clone(this.model.get('caption'));

        cloned = {};
        cloned.text = '';

        this.model.set('caption', cloned);
    }

    holder.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    // this.delegateEvents()

    // return this;

},
fireModel: function(e) {

    console.log('clicked');

},
});


// COLLECTION GENERATES INDIVIDUAL MODEL VIEW
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#social',
events: {
    'click #load-more': 'fetchCollection'
},
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new MyCollection();

    this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);

    this.collection.fetchData();
},
render: function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.cache.models.length; i ++) {
        modelView = new ModelView({model: this.collection.cache.models[i]});
    }

},
fetchCollection: function() {
    this.collection.fetchData();
},

});

// CREATE NEW COLLECTION
app = new AppView
```

Here's the template

```
<section id="social">

<div id="item-block">   
</div>

<div id="load-more">Load More</div>

</section>

<script type="text/template" id="template">

<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="details">
        <span class="caption"><%= caption.text %></span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="<%= images.standard_resolution.url %>" data-id="<%= id %>">
    </div>
</div>

</script>

<!-- JS LIBS AND BACKBONE SCRIPTS HERE -->
```

Comment: Can you add template file also (HTML)?

Comment: Shouldn't you say `'click .details'` instead of `'click.details'`? And why are you cloning the caption and then immediately assigning an empty object to the clone?

Comment: Caption is returned as either null or a nested object. Backbone doesn't recognize a change occurred if I modify the nested object, but I found a tutorial that recommended using a clone as a workaround (link below). It's an empty object so I can put it in the template as `caption.text`, otherwise it would be `caption` (null) and `caption.text` (something in there). `click .details` and `click.details` both function the same. https://www.crittercism.com/blog/nested-attributes-in-backbone-js-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note:

**First**, I want to mention that `tagName` property of `Backbone.View` should be the name of the HTML element (`div`, `ul`, ...., by default it's `div`).

**Second**, you attaching your modelView (childView) to appView from model view. It's can be implemented in a better
manner. Move that logic to the appView (parentView).

**Third**, use Underscore.js 's `each` method instead of `for` loop.

Use documentFragment to cache the childViews and append it at once, instead of one by one (performance optimization).

And the final look should be:

```
ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#template').html()),
    attributes: {
       'class': 'item-wrapper'
    },
    events: {
        'click .details': 'fireModel', // .details is a div inside of the template
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    fireModel: function(e) {
        console.log('clicked');
    },
});


// COLLECTION GENERATES INDIVIDUAL MODEL VIEW
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#social',
events: {
    'click #load-more': 'fetchCollection'
},
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new MyCollection();
    this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetchData();
},
render: function() {
    var buffer = document.createDocumentFragment();
    this.collection.each(function(model){
        if(model.attributes.caption == null) {
            // do your checks here
        } 
        var itemView = new ModelView({model: model});
        buffer.appendChild(itemView.render().el); // adding it to buffer   
    });

    this.$el.append(buffer); // appending all at once
}
});

// CREATE NEW COLLECTION
app = new AppView();
```

**Update**

In this way any time collection's `sync` event fired, it will append new itemViews to the parentView, so be sure to add checks there.

Comment: This did it thanks!! Good note on the DocumentFragment. You may want to update the bottom as `this.buffer` should be called as `buffer` however

Comment: @user2989731 if answer was helpful and solved your issue you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should insert some space between the event and the selector.

try

```
'click .details': 'fireModel'
```